# How to keep images quickly taken from same AVCaptureSession without app freezing?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to keep the images taken from an AVCaptureSession by storing them in an UIImage array.  I add each image to the array when it is taken.  After the 4th or 5th image the app freezes.  I've tried this and gotten the same behavior on 2 physical devices.  The CPU doesn't get above 21% according to that panel in Xcode.  Memory only ever gets to 21mb.  I am totally new to working with this part of AVFoundation and have no idea where to look or what to consider.  Eventually I'd like to display a collection view of the captured images in the same view controller.  I'd also like the user to be able to take 20+ pictures during the same life of the viewcontroller (same use of the camera).  I followed [this](https://medium.com/@barbulescualex/making-a-custom-camera-in-ios-ea44e3087563) tutorial.

If I put the app in the background and then immediately open it again I can immediately take 5 more pictures before it freezes.

If I compress the image before adding it to the array I can add 100+ with no issues

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice!
    var backInput: AVCaptureInput!

    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    var videoOutput : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!

    var takePicture = false

    var capturedImages: [UIImage] = []

    private let capturedImageImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.backgroundColor = .green
        return imageView
    }()

    private let imageCountLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .semibold)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    private static let captureButtonRadius: CGFloat = 40.0
    private let captureButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.layer.cornerRadius = CameraViewController.captureButtonRadius
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        setUpSubviews()

        captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(captureImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkPermissions()
        setUpAndStartCaptureSession()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    private func setUpSubviews() {

        view.addSubview(capturedImageImageView)
        view.addSubview(imageCountLabel)
        view.addSubview(captureButton)


        capturedImageImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        capturedImageImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        capturedImageImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -5.0).isActive = true
        capturedImageImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0).isActive = true

        imageCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: capturedImageImageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: capturedImageImageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: capturedImageImageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: capturedImageImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        captureButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Self.captureButtonRadius * 2.0).isActive = true
        captureButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Self.captureButtonRadius * 2.0).isActive = true
        captureButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        captureButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    private func checkPermissions() {

    }

    private func setUpAndStartCaptureSession() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            if self.captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(.photo) {
                self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
            }
            self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresCaptureDeviceForWideColor = true

            self.setUpInputs()
    
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setupPreviewLayer()
            }
    
            self.setupOutput()
    
            self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
    
    private func setUpInputs() {
    
        guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
            print("Failed to get back camera")
            return
        }
    
        backCamera = camera
    
        do {
            backInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
        } catch {
            print(#function, error.localizedDescription, error, separator: "\n")
        }
    
        if captureSession.canAddInput(backInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(backInput)
        } else {
            print("Can't add back camera input to capture session")
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    }

    func setupOutput(){

        videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        let videoQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue", qos: .userInteractive)
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoQueue)

        guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {
            print("Could not add video output")
            return
        }

        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        videoOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait
//        videoOutput.connections.first?.isVideoMirrored = false
    }

    @objc
    private func captureImage(){
        takePicture = true
    }

//    func switchCameraInput(){
//        //don't let user spam the button, fun for the user, not fun for performance
//        switchCameraButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
//
//        //reconfigure the input
//        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
//        if backCameraOn {
//            captureSession.removeInput(backInput)
//            captureSession.addInput(frontInput)
//            backCameraOn = false
//        } else {
//            captureSession.removeInput(frontInput)
//            captureSession.addInput(backInput)
//            backCameraOn = true
//        }
//
//        //deal with the connection again for portrait mode
//        videoOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait
//
//        //mirror the video stream for front camera
//        videoOutput.connections.first?.isVideoMirrored = !backCameraOn
//
//        //commit config
//        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
//
//        //acitvate the camera button again
//        switchCameraButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//    }
}

extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print(#function, "1")
        guard takePicture, let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        print(#function, "2")
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: buffer)
        let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.takePicture = false
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                self.capturedImages.append(uiImage)
            }
            self.capturedImageImageView.image = uiImage
            self.imageCountLabel.text = String(self.capturedImages.count)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "[weak self] in" or  "[unowned self] in" after async {

Comment: There’s no need if there’s no chance of a long-lasting retain cycle

Comment: Your method of appending images to `self.capturedImages` is not thread safe as global dispatch queues are concurrent queues.  You should create your own serial dispatch queue backed by the global queue and dispatch your array updates onto that queue, ensuring that only one thread can update the array at a time.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you provide the code to do this?  I am not sure about the "backed by the global queue" part

Comment: The flow doesn't look wrong, although I didn't dig too deep in it.
Maybe Paul is right to a degree (array is not thread-safe, but I would expect crash, not freezing if array was the issue).
So I think you will have to debug: first of narrow down to taking images vs saving (i.e. what if you disable saving, does it still freeze); then I would check what each thread is stuck on after the freeze; finally if nothing helps, try to run with various diagnostics flags to see if anything is pointed out.

Comment: You can create a dispatch queue using `DispatcQueue(label:"MyQueue", qos: .userInitiated, target: DispatchQueue.global(.userInitiated))`.  Make sure you create the queue once and store the reference into a property and always dispatch your array updates onto that queue.